# Use two field spearators in awk

Tags: bash, parsing, awk

I am trying to parse a string like this with bash

```
OPS |all|1234|ip:port1|name|state|number|id|phone=123;zip=123;state=AB;city=seattle .
OPS |all|1234|ip:port2|name|state|number|id|phone=123;zip=123;state=AB;city=spokane .
```

I want output like this

```
seattle | ip port1
spokane | ip port2
```

I was trying to use awk with this

```
awk -F'|' '{ n = split($4,array,"|"); printf "%s, %s\n", $4, array[n] }' file.txt
```

but its not printing the details that I want

Answer (score 4):

Use `-F` and `[]` to set multiple field separators.

```
awk -F '[|:= ]' '{print $14,"|",$4,$5}' file
```

Output:

```
seattle | ip port1
spokane | ip port2
```

Comment: I changed the input a little (a  space after OPS ) an the output is coming out like this

`AB;city | 1234 ip
AB;city | 1234 ip`

Comment: If you insert an additional field separator, then the output also changes.

Comment: yeah, I just changed your answer to increment by 1 and it worked